# How can you explain objects of unequal masses falling at the same rate using GR?

Tags: mass, spacetime, relativity, free-fall

Isn't gravity caused by the curvature of space-time, and the stronger it's curved the stronger the attraction? it makes more sense to me that if a heavier object is falling on earth it would fall faster than a lighter object since it curves space-time even more, or at least that's how I'm picturing it, but I know it's wrong, so how is it explained in general relativity? does the strength of gravity only depend on the curvature caused by the more massive object, i.e earth? or what?

Answer (score 5):

If Galileo had dropped the Moon and a pebble from a very tall tower, the Moon would have fallen noticeably faster, relative to the Earth. This is true in Newtonian physics as well as GR, and it does come from the fact that the Earth falls toward the Moon too, and harder than it falls towards the pebble. The assumption that small objects do not gravitate is an idealization, like the famous frictionless surface of physics homework.

Answer (score 3):

The strength of gravity is given by the space-time curvature caused by all the objects in the system, in this case both the earth and the falling object.

The problem is that you are ignoring the fact that the space-time curvature caused by the earth is many, many times larger than that caused by the falling object. Hence, the total curvature is to all intents and purposes the same as that of the earth only, and hence all objects will fall with (very nearly) the same acceleration.

EDIT
This is effectively the same as what Rob said in his comment while I was typing my answer...

Answer (score -1):

**How can you explain objects of unequal masses falling at the same rate using GR? 
up vote**

By explaining why light curves, then by using the wave nature of matter to explain why an electron falls down, and then explaining that an ensemble of electrons (and other particles) falls down at a rate that is irrespective of the number of particles in the ensemble.

**Isn't gravity caused by the curvature of space-time, and the stronger it's curved the stronger the attraction?**

No. See [various depictions of spacetime curvature](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=curved%20spacetime&hl=en-GB&gbv=2&tbm=isch&oq=&gs_l=). The spacetime curvature relates to the tidal force. The spacetime "tilt" relates to the force of gravity. The steeper the slope, the stronger the attraction. Note though that you need the curvature to *have* a slope. With no curvature at all, your spacetime is flat and level. This is why spacetime curvature is "the defining feature" of a gravitational field.

**it makes more sense to me that if a heavier object is falling on earth it would fall faster than a lighter object since it curves space-time even more, or at least that's how I'm picturing it, but I know it's wrong**

Actually, it isn't wrong, but for normal objects the effect is so slight as to be immeasurable. However if you dropped an Earth-sized object it would "fall down" at the usual 9.8 m/s/s, but the Earth would be attracted to it at 9.8 m/s/s too, so their mutual acceleration would be doubled.

**so how is it explained in general relativity? does the strength of gravity only depend on the curvature caused by the more massive object, i.e earth? or what?**

It's like what I said above. A pebble's gravitational field is so slight that you can't detect it. Ditto for a boulder. So we don't bother with it. Note though that if you dropped a Moon-sized object and a pebble, they'll still fall at the same rate because they act as a combined body in attracting the Earth. The Moon doesn't get ahead of the pebble.